# How can i run the admin module in zend 2.3?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-studio, zend-db-table, zend-framework-routing

I have tried so much through Googling but I have not found the right solution for that. Can anyone help me out? Even I tried to change the `module.config` file code through routing as well as I have tried `application.config` file to add module name in file but it is not working.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message
>   'Missing "type" option' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack.php:269
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack.php(163):
>   Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack->routeFromArray(Array) #1
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack.php(113):
>   Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack->routeFromArray(Array) #2
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack.php(140):
>   Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack->addRoute('controllers', Array) #3
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack.php(84):
>   Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack->addRoutes(Array) #4
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Router\Ht
>   in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php
>   on line 909

Comment: do you get any error? if not can you activate errors and let us know what the error says?

Comment: Hi Sudo.ie i have added the error please look at it.

Comment: It looks like routes issue, please paste the routes too use code format.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install the zf-commons and configure in module.config.php.

```
public
vendor
 zf-commons
  zfc-admin
  zfc-user
```

Please take a look at this.

https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcAdmin

Comment: in your composer.json, make some changes likes this and install via composer.                                                         "require": {
  "zf-commons/zfc-user": "dev-master",
  "zf-commons/zfc-admin": "dev-master",
  "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize": "1.4.*"
    }

Comment: i have make the changes in composer.json file but the problem remain same error is zfc admin module could not be initalized

Comment: did you add the modules, in the file config/application.config.php

Comment: yes i have added name zfcAdmin in application.cofig.php return array(
  'modules' => array(
        'ZendDeveloperTools',
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule',
        'Application',
  'ZfcAdmin',
    ),

Comment: did you find the zfc-base folder under the zfc-commons

Comment: you need to add the 'ZfcBase',
        'ZfcUser',
        'ZfcAdmin',
        'BjyAuthorize', module in the application. config.php

Comment: no i have not found zf base folder is it necessary to add this names to run the admin module ?

Comment: i am not sure on this, but i found zfcbase in the directory

Comment: from where i have to add zfc base folder

Answer (score 0):

I have created separate file for my module like module.config.php as well as module.php adding the namespace of my module name it works for me. and just add my module name in application.config.php .